# python 3.8 shared memory example giving different values

Tags: python, shared-memory, python-3.8

I am trying to use the new shared memory example in python 3.8 from this link https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

```
# In the first Python interactive shell
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8])  # Start with an existing NumPy array
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=a.nbytes)
# Now create a NumPy array backed by shared memory
b = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
b[:] = a[:]  # Copy the original data into shared memory
shname = shm.name  # We did not specify a name so one was chosen for us
print(shname)
print(a)
print(b)

# In either the same shell or a new Python shell on the same machine
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
# Attach to the existing shared memory block
existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shname)
# Note that a.shape is (6,) and a.dtype is np.int64 in this example
c = np.ndarray((6,), dtype=np.int64, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
print(c)
c[-1] = 888
print(c)
# Back in the first Python interactive shell, b reflects this change

# Clean up from within the second Python shell
del c  # Unnecessary; merely emphasizing the array is no longer used
existing_shm.close()

# Clean up from within the first Python shell
del b  # Unnecessary; merely emphasizing the array is no longer used
shm.close()
shm.unlink()  # Free and release the shared memory block at the very end
```

In the example, the output of `c` should be `array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8])` however when I run this I get:

```
wnsm_26020d1b
[1 1 2 3 5 8]
[1 1 2 3 5 8]
[ 4294967297 12884901890 34359738373           0           0           0]
[ 4294967297 12884901890 34359738373           0           0         888]
```

Did I totally miss something? Anyone else have this result?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica windows, you solved it thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `c` array needs to be created with the same dtype as `b`, but it's not. From the output shown, we can tell you're on Windows, where NumPy's default integer size is **32** bits, not 64. You've specified a dtype of `np.int64` for the second array, but `b` is using the default size of 32 bits.

Use `np.int_` for the second array to use NumPy's default integer dtype, or specify an explicit dtype for both `a` and `c` (which will also be used by `b`, because `b`'s dtype comes from `a`).